# Magento 2: How to override the luma default.xml

Tags: magento2, theme

I wish to do some customization in luma theme (default.xml).

I just created the default.xml file as specified below but it is not taking any effect.

[image: default.xml]

Note sure is this the correct way to override the theme???

Answer (score 2):

You must create and register a new theme:

[image]

You just need to create 2 files `theme.xml` and `registration.php` these are the examples for the theme in the image (Dayds). You should change that name for your own.

> app/design/frontend/Dayds/default/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Dayds/default',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/design/frontend/Dayds/default/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>DAYDS . Default</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

Then go to the backend and activate your new theme for the desired store.

Comment: Thanks.  I created a theme as you said and enabled it for my store. cleared the cache.  But the changes I do in `default.xml` (for Ex: I set `report.bugs` to remove `false` just to check) and it is not reflecting in the front-end.  But if I edit the luma default.xml directly it works.

Comment: In magento2 frontend design it's a real pain in the back, at least for me... you must remove cache, but need to remove var/view_generated and static/frontend almost every time you made a change. I deal with this a few hours until got some results. Try to change the logo filename should works.

Comment: BTW I had that example just working fine a few days, and after remove some modules (like shipping and payments gateways that I wont use) just stopped work. I had to reactivate all modules in order to get it working again.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am getting closer... Can you also explain me how to uninstall the theme??? I just removed the folder but still the dropdown shows the created theme...

Comment: Yes! just remove your theme record from the `theme` table. Note that, for some reason - you must respect the case that way: ThemeVendor > theme_name

Comment: @Malaiselvan BTW I forgot something... you must have your store set as `developer` mode.